# What does it mean a random variable to follow a certain distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable. For example, what does it mean $X$ to follow the binomial distribution $\operatorname{binom}(n,p)$ ($X\sim\operatorname{binom}(n,p)$)?

Comment: For starters, see wiki ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution))

Comment: I think this as follow: There are many types of "random" variables, all of them are random but the can have different behaviors. One way of formalize this is introducing the distributions, the are like "standars" randoms variables. So if you say $X$ is a random variable that follow a distribution $D$ then you are saying that you variable $X$ behaves like a variable with that distribution.

Comment: Also, [here's](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/) a crash course at the undergrad level.

Comment: The question is so basic that it is not clear what answer is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion a hidden but crucial fact (or rather definition) behind this is the notion of *random variable* and its extended meaning in combination with a probability space. Technically, a random variable $X$ is a measurable function $\Omega \to E$ from a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ to another measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$. Whenever the notion of distribution of a random variable comes into play, one also assumes that there is a probability measure $\Bbb P$ defined on $(\Omega , \mathcal F)$. Therefore, $(\Omega , \mathcal F, \Bbb P)$ is a so-called probability space.

We can now define the so-called pushforward measure of $\Bbb P$ by $X$ (denoted by $\Bbb P\circ X^{-1}$): For $A\in \mathcal E$ we set
$$\Bbb P \circ X^{-1} (A) := \Bbb P ( X^{-1} (A) ),$$
which is in this case again a probability measure. This works since $X: (\Omega, \mathcal F) \to (E,\mathcal E)$ is measurable. In the same way as *measurable function* was relabelled to *random variable*, in probability theory we speak of $\Bbb P\circ X^{-1}$ as **the distribution of $X$**.

If $\mu$ is a probability measure (for example Binomial distribution), then to say that $X$ follows this distribution (denoted by $X\sim \mu$) means that
$$\Bbb P\circ X^{-1} = \mu.$$

If $\mu$ is the Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, this means that for $k= 0, \ldots, n$ we have
$$\binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = \Bbb P\circ X^{-1} (\{k\}) = \mathbb P (X = k)$$